# How to align two different bullet points?

Tags: css, html

How do I make two different bullet points come next to each other ? I have this code of two categories: smoking and cholesterol. I would like cholesterol and all of its points to go to right of the page to level up with all smoking points.

```html
<b>Smoking</b>
<br>
<ul>
<li>20.9 percent of Non-Hispanic black males</li>
<li>19.8 percent of Non-Hispanic white males</li>
<li>17.9 percent of Non-Hispanic white females</li>
<li>14.3 percent of Hispanic males</li>
<li>13.4 percent of Non-Hispanic Asian males</li>
<li>13.8 percent of Non-Hispanic black females</li>
<li>7.1 percent of Hispanic females</li>
<li>4.1 percent of Non-Hispanic Asian females</li>
</ul>

<b> Cholesterol</b>

<ul>
<li>37.0 percent of NH white males</li>
<li>43.4 percent of NH white females</li>
<li>32.6 percent of NH black males</li>
<li>36.1 percent of NH black females</li>
<li>43.1 percent of Hispanic males</li>
<li>41.2 percent of Hispanic females</li>
<li>39.9 percent of NH Asian males</li>
<li>40.5 percent of NH Asian females</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Check out this [CSS floats](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/) article. You may also find using a CSS grid system framework such as [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid) is an easy way to get content side-by-side.

Comment: @sean Prefer `inline-block` over `float` - floating has many consequences that you can avoid if inline-block will do the job.
Yahyaotaif -- you should use a _heading_ tag such as `<h1>` or `<h3>`, not a `<b>` for your headings. Mark-up things for what they _are_, not how you want them to _look_, then use CSS to make them look the way you want. (for example, if h1 is semantically correct but too big, make it smaller with a css rule `h1 { font-size: 15px; }`)

Comment: @StephenP If floats are used correctly, there are no negative consequences. They also give you the ability to use clears when needed, affording more control over layout. `inline-block` will get the job done fine though, in this example.

Comment: @sean - I agree with your statement, but I think inline-block is more often the better solution, and now we also have `flex` and `grid` and none of these require the extra non-semantic markup like `<div class="clearfix"></div>`. I strive for a page that defines the semantic structure of the content.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could wrap each list and list heading, and apply `display: inline-block`to the wrapper.

```css
.content {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <b>Smoking</b>
  <ul>
    <li>20.9 percent of Non-Hispanic black males</li>
    <li>19.8 percent of Non-Hispanic white males</li>
    <li>17.9 percent of Non-Hispanic white females</li>
    <li>14.3 percent of Hispanic males</li>
    <li>13.4 percent of Non-Hispanic Asian males</li>
    <li>13.8 percent of Non-Hispanic black females</li>
    <li>7.1 percent of Hispanic females</li>
    <li>4.1 percent of Non-Hispanic Asian females</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <b> Cholesterol</b>
  <ul>
    <li>37.0 percent of NH white males</li>
    <li>43.4 percent of NH white females</li>
    <li>32.6 percent of NH black males</li>
    <li>36.1 percent of NH black females</li>
    <li>43.1 percent of Hispanic males</li>
    <li>41.2 percent of Hispanic females</li>
    <li>39.9 percent of NH Asian males</li>
    <li>40.5 percent of NH Asian females</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Recommend changing the class name to "inline-block" for clarity, since "block" is also an acceptable value for the `display` property.

Comment: @Yeah good point. Intention here was 'block of content' but I see how it could be confusing.

Comment: @sol Is there a way to increase the space between both of them ?

Comment: @sol I figure that out by using padding-right and left.

Answer (score 0):

You could make them in a table "Smoking" and "Cholesterol" in the first row
and there data on the other row

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><b>Smoking</b></td>
    <td><b>Cholesterol</b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
        <ul>
            <li>20.9 percent of Non-Hispanic black males</li>
            <li>19.8 percent of Non-Hispanic white males</li>
            <li>17.9 percent of Non-Hispanic white females</li>
            <li>14.3 percent of Hispanic males</li>
            <li>13.4 percent of Non-Hispanic Asian males</li>
            <li>13.8 percent of Non-Hispanic black females</li>
            <li>7.1 percent of Hispanic females</li>
            <li>4.1 percent of Non-Hispanic Asian females</li>
            </ul>
    </td>
    <td>
        <ul>
            <li>37.0 percent of NH white males</li>
            <li>43.4 percent of NH white females</li>
            <li>32.6 percent of NH black males</li>
            <li>36.1 percent of NH black females</li>
            <li>43.1 percent of Hispanic males</li>
            <li>41.2 percent of Hispanic females</li>
            <li>39.9 percent of NH Asian males</li>
            <li>40.5 percent of NH Asian females</li>
            </ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

then you can change the cellspacing as you like.

Comment: This is using a table in order to do layout, which is very 1995 and strongly discouraged for modern browsers. Tables should be used for _tabular data_ not for positioning things where you want.

Comment: ?? Tables are for tabular data. If this is tabular data scrap the list and place the content in table cells.